# How to give the user unlimited views

Tags: php

I'm trying to give the user an unlimited option in my database but I'm not sure how to do this. I have set the default as 10 because they have 10 views and for each page they are viewing, it will count down. Once it reaches 0, the user will have to register again unless they have made payment but not sure how to make the views unlimited

I'm confused as to what to do here because I can't find any option to set the views as unlimited.

```
<?php
include_once 'navbar.php';

if(!$_SESSION['u_uid']) {
    header("Location: index.php?medical_subscriptionplan_process=notlogin");
    exit();
} else {
    include_once 'includes/dbh.php';
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $views = strip_tags($_POST['subscriptionplan']);

        if ($views == '') {
            header("Location: index.php?medical_subscriptionplan_process=emptied");
            exit();
        } else {
            if ($views == '10_views') {
                $views = 10;
                $sql = "UPDATE users
                        SET views = ?
                        WHERE user_uid = ?;

                       ";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    echo "SQL error";
                } else {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $views, $_SESSION['u_uid']);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                } 
            } else {
                if ($views == '100_views') {
                    $views = 100;
                    $sql = "UPDATE users
                        SET views = ?
                        WHERE user_uid = ?;";
                    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                        echo "SQL error";
                    } else {
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $views, $_SESSION['u_uid']);
                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    } 
                } else {
                    if ($views == 'unlimited') {
                        $views = NULL;
                        $sql = "UPDATE users
                            SET views = ?
                            WHERE user_uid = ?;";
                        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                            echo "SQL error";
                        } else {
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $views, $_SESSION['u_uid']);
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        header("Location: index.php?medical_subscriptionplan_process=sucess");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could start with setting the `flag=1` and count up, and set it to zero for unlimited. If `flag===0`: do not count up. If `flag > 10`: register again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To indicate unlimited views in your database, you just need to add -1 in your database view column otherwise set it with some other positive integer, then check for the condition,

```
if (views == -1){
  // user has paid for unlimited view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add flag (just like "is_unlimited") in database to check customers access limit

```
if($isunlmited==1){
   //always allow access
}else{
   //check for 10_views limit
}
```

Comment: but in my database, i set the views as int to 10 as a default

Comment: for unlimited access customer, set flag("is_unlimited" table field other than views field) to 1 otherwise keep it zero.... if flag is zero then check its limited access otherwise allow customer directly (as mentioned in above if-else statement of flag)